# Validating phone numbers using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a phone number. The website is US based but the clients can be from all over the world. I am using jQuery to validate the input. I would be very thankful for the hints given for validation. Thanks.

```
<input 
     name="phone"  
     type="text" 
     id="phone" 
     minlength="7"
     maxlength="15" 
     style="
               font-family: Verdana;
               color:#FFFFFF;
               font-size: 13px;
               background-color: #0E0E0F;
               border: 1px solid #740086;
               width:385px;
               margin-bottom:10px;
           "
     size="385"
     value="Phone #"
     onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
     onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User JQuery validation engine..its easy..cool and the cleanest validation framework I have seen yet..`http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/`
This plugin already take care for phone number validation..if thats not sufficient then you can add your own custom regular expression to perform the validation.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phoneformat.com/

You could use this library to validate. It also does formatting of the number for you. Really impressive library

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers vary greatly from zone to zone. The easiest way to cope with this is to just validate for emptyness. However if you truly need to validate a phone number, you will have to take into account the area code, the region and try to ask the user not to input any special characters. For example, if I wanted to validate a cell phone number from buenos aires, argentina I would use at least 2 input fields: one for the area code, and one for the actual number.

Another solution is given [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number)

Yet another: Ask the user for the country code (or to select it from a drop-down list), then the area code (could be another drop-down, albeit a dynamically set one would be nice, taking into account the country already selected), and then another input for the actual number. Dont try to validate the number itself, but rather ask the user to not input any special chars or spaces, and check if a number was entered.
However, I don't think it is really worth the effort. If you REALLY need to have the user's real number, you should have someone call that number and verify it

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using a *standard* [jquery validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It has built-in *templates* for validating URLs, emails and even [US phone numbers](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS)--among others.

The next challenge would be how to extend the validator plugin to validate against *any* phone number. Phone number formats vary from territory to territory so you can restrict the validation to what characters can be accepted instead. For example, only accept digits (0-9), parenthesis, dashes and the like.

You can then extend the plugin to something like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneAny", function(phone_number, element) {
phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
```

with the regex matching your accepted set of characters aforementioned.